# c++ forward declare partial specialization multiple times give error in gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, metadata

Inside the classes of my game engine, I use a macro to create meta data for my member variables. To be able to index the meta data, I use partially specialized structs, which have an index as the first parameter (see example below). In order to specialize the structs, I have to declare the base meta data struct, which I do by simply forward declaring the struct. The problem occurs when I inherit a class using the forward declaration of the meta data structure (Only in gcc above version 11). I hope the example clarifies my problem. My question is now, is gcc here correct or is it a compiler bug. If so can any one provide a workaround?

```
// Example for METADATA macro, real macro is more complex, but you get the idea.
#define METADATA(type,val,...) \
template<typename field_index, typename... avoid_explicit_specialization> \
struct field_data; \
template<typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>   \
struct field_data<std::integral_constant<size_t, __COUNTER__>, avoid_explicit_specialization...>{ /* meta infos */ };

struct Base
{ 
    template<typename field_index, typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>
    struct field_data;

    //template<typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>   
    //struct field_data<std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>, avoid_explicit_specialization...>{ /* meta infos */ };

    // METADATA(int, var0)
    // METADATA(int, var1)
};
struct Derived : Base
{ 
    template<typename field_index, typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>
    struct field_data; // ok

    //template<typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>   
    //struct field_data<std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>, avoid_explicit_specialization...>{ /* meta infos */ };


    template<typename field_index, typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>
    struct field_data; // error 

    //template<typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>   
    //struct field_data<std::integral_constant<size_t, 1>, avoid_explicit_specialization...>{ /* meta infos */ };
};
```

Goal: Create a meta system, without errors.

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: The reduced example is not equivalent, moreover they are forward declared, that makes a difference as well.

Comment: The forward declaration(the are outside the class) are declares different class than what is actually being declared inside the class. The ones outside the class are in global scope. That is, they don't make any difference here.

Answer (score 1):

> is gcc here correct or is it a compiler bug.

The program is **ill-formed** as per [class.mem.general](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#5) and *gcc is correct in giving a diagnostic(in this case rejecting) the code*:

> A **member shall not be declared twice in the member-specification**, except that
>
> - a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined, and
> - an enumeration can be introduced with an opaque-enum-declaration and later redeclared with an enum-specifier.

As you can see from the above reference, we're not allowed to declare a member class template twice in the *member-specification*.

Comment: Isn't the first one cited the case? Could you clarify the difference?

Comment: Is a partial specialization declaration a redeclaration of the member? It is explicitly permitted to _define_ a partial specialization in every scope that the primary template may be defined. It would be weird if _definitions_ are allowed but non-defining declarations are not.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't realize that the primary member class template is declared twice in the example.

Comment: @Moritz Sure, the first bullet point is referring to [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xfxzE1Mxq). Note in the above [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xfxzE1Mxq), the 2nd non-defining declaration `struct D;` is invalid but `struct D{};` which is a definition as well as a declaration is valid as per the cited reference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, can you think of any trick, to make the meta macro work? Maybe some way to detect an existing forward declaration and then skip this part in den second macro somehow?

Comment: @Moritz It may be possible but I would recommend asking a new separate question for that follow up question. Comment section has a word limit and usually a post should ask one question per post. Also comments gets deleted often by moderators and users so answers and question should not be posted on comments. Feel free to ask a new separate question for the follow up question.