# Meta system inner template class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, macros, metaprogramming

This is the follow up question to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77727813/c-forward-declare-partial-specialization-multiple-times-give-error-in-gcc/77727962?noredirect=1#comment137044843_77727962). How do I achieve the following code functionality, without declaring the general template every time? I could use static functions, in which I overload the argument, but I prefer structs. I further could add a meta macro to every class, which adds the general template def, but that is also a lot of code to change. Maybe some way to emulate the specialization. I am open to any help.

```
// Example for METADATA macro, real macro is more complex, but you get the idea.
#define METADATA(type,val,...) \
template<typename field_index, typename... avoid_explicit_specialization> \
struct field_data; \
template<typename... avoid_explicit_specialization>   \
struct field_data<std::integral_constant<size_t, __COUNTER__>, avoid_explicit_specialization...>{ /* meta infos */ };

struct Base
{ 
    METADATA(int, var0)
    METADATA(int, var1)
};
struct Derived : Base
{ 
    METADATA(int, var2)
    METADATA(int, var3)
};
```

Goal: A simple meta system macro.

Comment: *but you get the idea.* I don't get it. `type,val,...` are not used.

Comment: It will be used in the meta Infos

Comment: How about split the MACRO in 2? one for the class, and one for the members.

Comment: That would be the last resort, but I hoped for a better solution.